# tcp nonblocking not working

Tags: c++, tcp

I  have a tcp server and 2 clients that want to connect to it. The way this clients will connect is that 1 of them, lets call it `client1` will be all the time connected sending data and the other, `client2`, will eventually connect, send small amount of data and disconnect. I set `O_NONBLOCK` option on. The behaviour I experience is that the client that is continuosly sending data,on server side, receives one message and wait for the next connection... Here is what i tried so far(The code is the while where in any moment the `client2` wants to connect and send data and disconnect):

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    error("ERROR on binding");

listen(sockfd, 5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

int flag = 0;

do {

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    if(newsockfd > 0){
        //Sockets Layer Call: inet_ntop()
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(cli_addr.sin6_addr),client_addr_ipv6, 100);
        printf("Incoming connection from client having IPv6 address: %s\n",client_addr_ipv6);


        n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 49,0);

        if(n > 0){

            send_data(argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],argv[5],argv[6],buffer);
            memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        }
    }
    newsockfd2 = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr2, &clilen);

    //Sockets Layer Call: inet_ntop()
    if(newsockfd2 > 0){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(cli_addr2.sin6_addr),client_addr_ipv6, 100);
        printf("Incoming connection from client having IPv6 address: %s\n",client_addr_ipv6);
        n2= recv(newsockfd2, buffer, 49, 0);
        if(n2 > 0){

            send_data(argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],argv[5],argv[6],buffer);
            memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        }
    }


}while(!flag);
```

I also tried adding the option inside of the while and setting nonblocking on `newsockfd` and `newsockfd2`but same result.

What am I doing wrong? thanks ! :D

Comment: And what happens with the code you show? Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? None of the system functions returns with an error? And why are you doing the same thing twice?

Comment: open two sockets instead of jumping between the two. And with non-blocking communication you are supposed to use epoll (or select, or whatever thing of that kind). Otherwise nobody waits for nothing, that is the whole purpose of non-blocking.

Comment: @Slava , so you are telling me that 1 socket can't handle 2 connections at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

When a new socket is retuned from accept, you must create a new thread with this socket so that one-to-one communication will be handled in this thread. The socked doesn't have to ne non-blocking.